# I want to take the user width with js and define it with css width

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, sass

```
const showInfo = (key) => {
setShowsInfo(true);
setSelectedPhoto(key);
setScreenWidth(window.innerWidth);
setScreenHeight(window.innerHeight);
// console.log(key)
}
```

This is the relevant part of my code. I'm going to make a popup and apply a blackout with
the css after method in the popup. I want the after feature to cover the entire page and
darken it, so I want to take the wıtdt and height properties from the user's input and
transfer the css, but I want to transfer the css code, but I can't figure out how to do it.
I leave it above and waiting for your suggestions

Comment: I believe what you want is a modal that pops over the content and displays some information about what was clicked. If so, you can simplify the above by just using static CSS properties: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-modal-body-scroll-brx0pb).